# Pass a username to a command

Tags: batch-file

So I want to create a batch file that logs me into a server and runs some complicated commands for me in order to streamline my process.  I have everything figured out except the initial login.

The problem I am running into is that when I run the login command, it prompts for a username, and then a password.  How do I get the batch file to enter values for this prompts as they come up to get past this step?

So for my purposes the order looks like:

1. Run login command
2. Enter username into command prompt
3. Enter Username into command prompt
4. Enter a third value into the command prompt
5. Run some commands on the server

My problem is I can't figure out how to pass values to those command prompts. Can anyone help? I've been searching for hours and haven't found anything helpful because I don't know the terminology.

Comment: Whatever method you're using to connect to this server should already have a way of passing the username to it. What are you using? SSH? FTP?

Comment: It is nothing of the sort, it's a custom login client that does not have a unique way of passing a username/password to it other than the prompts.

Comment: Please mock your dev team incessantly for me.

Comment: Will do.  Please let me know if this question is unanswerable or not useful for the community and I will remove it.

Comment: Well, you're not going to get a pure batch answer since the program you're using has no command-line interface, but someone will likely come in in a bit and recommend a batch/vbscript that uses SendKeys (or they'll recommend AutoIt if you're allowed to install third-party software).

Comment: Thank you @SomethingDark